# In R, group by 2 columns and then compute percentage frequencies for a 3rd column

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

Title is a bit wordy, but the example below very clearly highlights what I am struggling with. I am able to achieve the desired result with a for-loop, but would prefer a non-for-loop solution for this:

```
dput(mydf)
structure(list(shooterFullName = c("Ky Bowman", "Ky Bowman", 
"Ky Bowman", "Ky Bowman", "Ky Bowman", "Ky Bowman", "Ky Bowman", 
"Ky Bowman", "Ky Bowman", "Ky Bowman", "Ky Bowman", "Ky Bowman", 
"Markell Johnson", "Markell Johnson", "Markell Johnson", "Markell Johnson", 
"Markell Johnson", "Markell Johnson", "Markell Johnson", "Markell Johnson", 
"Markell Johnson", "Markell Johnson", "Markell Johnson", "Markell Johnson"
), distanceCategory = c("atr2", "atr2", "lng2", "lng2", "lng3", 
"lng3", "mid2", "mid2", "sht2", "sht2", "sht3", "sht3", "atr2", 
"atr2", "lng2", "lng2", "lng3", "lng3", "mid2", "mid2", "sht2", 
"sht2", "sht3", "sht3"), season = c("1718", "1819", "1718", "1819", 
"1718", "1819", "1718", "1819", "1718", "1819", "1718", "1819", 
"1718", "1819", "1718", "1819", "1718", "1819", "1718", "1819", 
"1718", "1819", "1718", "1819"), plAttempts = c(49L, 12L, 30L, 
10L, 60L, 29L, 25L, 20L, 46L, 44L, 66L, 34L, 23L, 10L, 4L, 3L, 
15L, 13L, 12L, 8L, 27L, 16L, 31L, 27L)), row.names = c(NA, -24L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

head(mydf, 18)
   shooterFullName distanceCategory season plAttempts
   <chr>           <chr>            <chr>       <int>
 1 Ky Bowman       atr2             1718           49
 2 Ky Bowman       atr2             1819           12
 3 Ky Bowman       lng2             1718           30
 4 Ky Bowman       lng2             1819           10
 5 Ky Bowman       lng3             1718           60
 6 Ky Bowman       lng3             1819           29
 7 Ky Bowman       mid2             1718           25
 8 Ky Bowman       mid2             1819           20
 9 Ky Bowman       sht2             1718           46
10 Ky Bowman       sht2             1819           44
11 Ky Bowman       sht3             1718           66
12 Ky Bowman       sht3             1819           34
13 Markell Johnson atr2             1718           23
14 Markell Johnson atr2             1819           10
15 Markell Johnson lng2             1718            4
16 Markell Johnson lng2             1819            3
17 Markell Johnson lng3             1718           15
18 Markell Johnson lng3             1819           13
```

My goal is as followed - I would like to add a new column `distFreq` that groups by `shooterFullName` and `season`, and then computes the percentage of a players `plAttempts` that falls into the row's respective `distanceCategory`.

Here is an example that uses a for-loop, however I would like to avoid using a for loop for a variety of reasons.

```
mydf$distFreq = 0
all_players = unique(mydf$shooterFullName)
all_years = unique(mydf$season)
for(i in 1:length(all_players)) {
  for(j in 1:length(all_years)) {
    subsetdf <- mydf %>%
      dplyr::filter(shooterFullName == all_players[i]) %>%
      dplyr::filter(season == all_years[j])

    subsetdf <- subsetdf %>%
      dplyr::mutate(distFreq = plAttempts / sum(plAttempts))

    mydf$distFreq[mydf$shooterFullName == all_players[i] & mydf$season == all_years[j]] = subsetdf$distFreq
  }
}

head(mydf, 12)
   shooterFullName distanceCategory season plAttempts distFreq
   <chr>           <chr>            <chr>       <int>    <dbl>
 1 Ky Bowman       atr2             1718           49   0.178 
 2 Ky Bowman       atr2             1819           12   0.0805
 3 Ky Bowman       lng2             1718           30   0.109 
 4 Ky Bowman       lng2             1819           10   0.0671
 5 Ky Bowman       lng3             1718           60   0.217 
 6 Ky Bowman       lng3             1819           29   0.195 
 7 Ky Bowman       mid2             1718           25   0.0906
 8 Ky Bowman       mid2             1819           20   0.134 
 9 Ky Bowman       sht2             1718           46   0.167 
10 Ky Bowman       sht2             1819           44   0.295 
11 Ky Bowman       sht3             1718           66   0.239 
12 Ky Bowman       sht3             1819           34   0.228
```

A `dplyr` solution would be preferable, but I am struggling with dplyr with this - any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may do the following:

```
mydf %>% group_by(shooterFullName, season) %>% 
  mutate(distFreq = plAttempts / sum(plAttempts))
# A tibble: 24 x 5
# Groups:   shooterFullName, season [4]
#    shooterFullName distanceCategory season plAttempts distFreq
#    <chr>           <chr>            <chr>       <int>    <dbl>
#  1 Ky Bowman       atr2             1718           49   0.178 
#  2 Ky Bowman       atr2             1819           12   0.0805
#  3 Ky Bowman       lng2             1718           30   0.109 
#  4 Ky Bowman       lng2             1819           10   0.0671
#  5 Ky Bowman       lng3             1718           60   0.217 
#  6 Ky Bowman       lng3             1819           29   0.195 
#  7 Ky Bowman       mid2             1718           25   0.0906
#  8 Ky Bowman       mid2             1819           20   0.134 
#  9 Ky Bowman       sht2             1718           46   0.167 
# 10 Ky Bowman       sht2             1819           44   0.295 
# ... with 14 more rows
```

Which is exactly what you did except that the usage of `group_by` makes things much more concise.

Comment: This only works on the test data because each `season` only has one row per `distanceCategory`/`shooter` combo

Comment: And the downvote is for...? @IceCreamToucan, indeed, the OP also exploited that.

Comment: Ok, just note that this doesn't compute "the percentage of a players plAttempts that falls into the row's respective distanceCategory", just something that happens to coincide with that for this data. p.s. downvote didn't come from me

Comment: The downvote is really not necessary considering this solves the issue as shown. I guess you could sum, then ungroup/group again if you wanted to extend this logic - `mydf %>%
  group_by(shooterFullName, season) %>%
  mutate(seassum = sum(plAttempts)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(shooterFullName, season, distanceCategory) %>%
  summarise(distFreq = plAttempts / seassum)
`

Comment: Both of you are right, of course. As the OP already has a solution that works for his actual data (meaning that there is 1 row per distanceCategory/shooter/season) *and* he only wants to simplify it, I didn't see a reason to unnecessarily complicate mine.

Comment: @thelatemail The solution you provide gives the same results as this answer. `mydf %>% 
  group_by(shooterFullName, season, distanceCategory) %>% 
  mutate(seassum = sum(plAttempts)) %>%  
  group_by(shooterFullName, season) %>% 
  mutate(distFreq2 = seassum/sum(plAttempts)) ` works the same as my posted answer

Comment: Confirming that each season only has 1 row per distanceCategory / shooter combo

Comment: thought group_by, well, uhh, grouped the data - so surprised that this works as such.

Comment: ahhhhhhh its the summarise that actually reduces the number of rows!